# How to draw route when user walking or driving along the road

Tags: ios, swift, path-finding

Hi i am beginner in Ios and in my project i am trying to draw the route when user walking or driving along the road but route is not plotting properly please help me some one (if any body have idea please modify my code and post working code)

### Mycode is below:-

### ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>

{

    IBOutlet MKMapView *myMap;
    CLLocationManager *locmanager;
}


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *myMap;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *allPinsArr;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MKPolylineView *lineView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MKPolyline *polyline;

- (IBAction)startButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

### ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Location.h"
#import "Pin.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D curentLocation;
    CLLocation *oldLocation1;
    CLLocation *newLocation1;
    NSUserDefaults *def;
    BOOL isfirstRun;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myMap,allPinsArr,polyline,lineView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    myMap.delegate = self;
    locmanager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locmanager setDelegate:self];

    if ([locmanager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
    {
        [locmanager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    [locmanager setDistanceFilter:10.0f];
    [locmanager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
    [myMap setShowsUserLocation:YES];
 }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 }

- (IBAction)startButton:(id)sender {

    [myMap removeOverlay:self.polyline];
    [lineView removeFromSuperview];
    [myMap removeAnnotations:myMap.annotations];
    allPinsArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [locmanager startUpdatingLocation];
 }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
 {

    newLocation1 = newLocation;
    oldLocation1 = oldLocation;
    curentLocation = newLocation.coordinate;
    [self checkthelocationisPreviousornot:newLocation :oldLocation];

 }

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

// check new location is previous or not
-(void)checkthelocationisPreviousornot:(CLLocation *)newLocation :(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    //For Sqlite Reference
    NSInteger idVal = [def integerForKey:@"id"];

    if (idVal==0) {

        idVal=1;
    }

    [def setInteger:idVal forKey:@"id"];

    if ((newLocation.coordinate.latitude!=oldLocation.coordinate.latitude || newLocation.coordinate.longitude!=oldLocation.coordinate.longitude) || isfirstRun==YES) {

        double distance =[oldLocation distanceFromLocation:newLocation];

        NSString *distStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",distance];

        //Adding data in sqlite
       // [self insertcoordinatestodatabase:curentLocation :idVal :@"" :@""];

        [self addingCoordinatesToarray:newLocation.coordinate :distStr];
    }
}

//add co-ordinates to array
-(void)addingCoordinatesToarray:(CLLocationCoordinate2D )coordinates :(NSString *)distance {

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, 1000, 1000);
    [myMap setRegion:region animated:YES];

    Pin *pin =[[Pin alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinates title:@"Entry point" distance:distance myimage:nil videopath:nil];

    [myMap addAnnotation:pin];

    [allPinsArr addObject:pin];

    [self drawline];

}

-(void)drawline{

    [self drawLineSubroutine];
    [self drawLineSubroutine];
}

- (void)drawLineSubroutine {

    // remove polyline if one exists
    [myMap removeOverlay:self.polyline];

    // create an array of coordinates from allPins
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[allPinsArr.count];
    int i = 0;
    for (Pin *currentLoc in allPinsArr) {

        coordinates[i] = currentLoc.coordinate;
        i++;
    }
    // create a polyline with all cooridnates

    polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:allPinsArr.count];
    [myMap addOverlay:polyline];
    self.polyline = polyline;

}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKOverlayView* overlayView = nil;

    if(overlay == self.polyline)
    {
        //if we have not yet created an overlay view for this overlay, create it now.
        if (self.lineView) {
            [self.lineView removeFromSuperview];
        }
        self.lineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.polyline];
        self.lineView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.lineView.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        self.lineView.lineWidth = 10;
        overlayView = self.lineView;
    }

    return overlayView;
}


@end
```

### Location.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@import MapKit;

@interface Location : NSObject<MKAnnotation>{

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *loctionName;
    NSString *distance;
    NSString *mediaPath;

}
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *loctionName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *distance;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *mediaPath;
@end
```

### Location.m

```
#import "Location.h"

@implementation Location
@synthesize coordinate,loctionName,distance,mediaPath;

@end
```

### Pin.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@import MapKit;

@interface Pin : NSObject <MKAnnotation> 

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int wayPointID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *distance;
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIImage *myimage;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *videopath;

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate title:(NSString *)title distance:(NSString *)distance myimage:(UIImage *)myimage videopath:(NSString *)videopath;

@end
```

### Pin.m

```
#import "Pin.h"

@implementation Pin

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate title:(NSString *)title distance:(NSString *)distance myimage:(UIImage *)myimage videopath:(NSString *)videopath{

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _coordinate = newCoordinate;
        _title = title;
        _distance = distance;
        _myimage = myimage;
        _videopath = videopath;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Check this posts   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319643/how-to-draw-a-route-between-two-locations-using-mapkit-in-swift

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27558912/draw-polyline-using-swift