# New Xcode beta new problems: MKGeodesicPolyline

Tags: ios, xcode, geodesic-sphere

The brand new Xcode version, in addition to removing a wide nume of place where to add an empty function call, introduced a funny problem with an simple piece of code drawing a geodetic path:

```
func drawPolyline(from startLocation: CLLocation, endLocation:CLLocation) {
    let point1 = startLocation.coordinate
    let point2 = endLocation.coordinate
    var points: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]
    points = [point1, point2]
    var coordinates=points[0]
    let geodesic = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count:2)
    self.mapView.add(geodesic)
}
```

The compiler complaints about an:

> Ambiguous use of 'init(coordinates:count:)'

When I try to click on the given options, I am always led to that line. I tried to clean the project to no avail.

Comment: Can you try to define `coordinates` as `UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `MKGeodesicPolyline` would use either `UnsafePointer` or `UnsafeMutablePointer` using the type `CLLocationCoordinate2D` which you defined as points, so you'd likely want:

```
let geodesic = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: points, count: 2)
```

↳ [Apple Developer : CLLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/)

Comment: In fact , the new beta does not apparently accept the subscribing: by using let geodesic = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: points, count:2) it compiles without problems, even if the error returned for such a chang of syntax was much less than clear. I think all the examples on the web must be corrected. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

let geodesic = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count:2)

- remove "&" symbol before the coordinates . This solved the issue.